# Find out if font has monospaced numbers

Tags: windows, winapi, fonts, monospace

There are proportional fonts (i.e. not monospaced) that nevertheless provide monospaced numbers. E.g. see this Excel screenshot using Arial:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Note how the numbers are nicely aligned. How can I find out programmatically (probably WinAPI) if a font supports this feature?

Comment: How about writing the various strings, "0000", "1111" ... "9999" into a test device context (having selected your test font) and then getting the width with `GetTextExtent()`? Or are you looking for something more elegant/simple?

Comment: I'd like something simpler, maybe even an equivalent to `CF_FIXEDPITCHONLY` so I can directly use it in a common font dialog. It's just a "nice to have" in our app.

Comment: You won't find an API for that because there isn't any specific metadata value within the font file to indicate "the glyphs for digits in this font have fixed width". Some fonts may support both proportional and fixed-width ("lining") digits, in which case the font is likely to support the 'lnum' OpenType Layout feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_ko#lnum). You should pick a font that supports this feature and then explicitly activate that feature when drawing the text.

Comment: @PeterConstable - you should post your comment as an answer IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find an API for that because there isn't any specific metadata value within the font file to indicate "the glyphs for digits in this font have fixed width". Some fonts may support both proportional and fixed-width ("lining") digits, in which case the font is likely to support the ['lnum' OpenType Layout feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_ko#lnum). You should pick a font that supports this feature and then explicitly activate that feature when drawing the text.